# Are there any tools/tricks/plugins that help me count the number of objects there are in a JSON url in Google Chrome itself?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

For example in the json url https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos

I want to know how many objects there are in the main array, without having to leave chrome.

Comment: That's not a JSON URL (there's no such thing, afaik), it's a regular URL that responds with a JSON document that you would typically parse and go from there...

Comment: Maybe you should ask on Super User if you're looking for something with a GUI.

Comment: @ssube yes, i know you parse that JSON document, but can I do it on chrome itself, and if so then how? For example, can I parse it in the console of developers tool or is there a plugin that will help me do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys(obj).length`, where `obj` is the JSON returned from the API.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a request for that data and then count the number of records in the array of the JSON returned. You can open the Chrome Dev Tools (F12 by default) and paste the code below into the console.

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos').then(response => response.json().then(data => console.log('Records: ' + data.length)))
```

Or you can do it manually by loading opening the link in your browser and then searching for a unique key like "full_name" in the objects.